# Multiplying values between csv documents with the same date

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 2 csv documents which looks as follows:

csv_1, For example:

> 2021-01-04, 137.03, 133.21
> 2021-12-13, 141.61, 133.48
> 2021-01-07, 143.3, 133.48

csv_2, For example:

> 2021-01-04, 8.1881
> 2021-01-05, 8.2144
> 2021-01-07, 8.1876

What I want to accomplish is to have the values 137.03 and 133.21 multiplied with 8.1881 and do this with every item in the csv documents.

I attempted to open the documents in a readable state, and with indexes and a for loop, I tried to accomplish this task. I would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Your file has no header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas DataFrame to simplify the steps:

create two dataframe for 2 csv files (You can store the value in different dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_1.csv', names=['Date', 'A', 'B'], header=None))

df1 = pd.read_csv('csv_2.csv', names=['Date', 'C'], header=None))
```

used print statement to see/print the value

```
print(df[["A", "B"]].multiply(df1["C"], axis="index"))
```

if you want to store the value you can store in new dataframe

```
df2 = df[["A", "B"]].multiply(df1["C"], axis="index")
```

note : header - None is used to trim column names is already exists in CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

csv_1_path = r"C:\Users\WX847\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\csv1.csv"
csv_2_path = r"C:\Users\WX847\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\csv2.csv"

cvs_1_data_list = []
with open(csv_1_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    for row in reader1:
        cvs_1_data_list.append(row)
print(cvs_1_data_list)

cvs_2_data_list = []
with open(csv_2_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2)
    for row in reader2:
        cvs_2_data_list.append(row)
print(cvs_2_data_list)


csv_1_date_dict = {row[0].strip(): [row[1].strip(), row[2].strip()] for row in cvs_1_data_list}
csv_2_date_dict = {row[0].strip(): [row[1].strip()] for row in cvs_2_data_list}

for k_date in csv_2_date_dict:
    if k_date in csv_1_date_dict:
        one_res = float(csv_1_date_dict[k_date][0])*float(csv_1_date_dict[k_date][1]) * float(csv_2_date_dict[k_date][0])
        print(one_res)


"""
[['2021-01-04', ' 137.03', ' 133.21'], ['2021-12-13', ' 141.61', ' 133.48'], ['2021-01-07', ' 143.3', ' 133.48']]
[['2021-01-04', ' 8.1881'], ['2021-01-05', ' 8.2144'], ['2021-01-07', ' 8.1876']]
149463.66384103004
156609.8255184
"""
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have applied the code, and would like to take it a step further. I should've been clearer in the start. The value from the csv_2 should be multiplied with the corresponding values on the csv_document, but based on the date at hand and not relative position. So that the 2021-08-12 would be multiplied with the value at the same date. This is because the csv_1 document is substantially larger than the csv_2 document. Do you know of the general principles that would be required to do such a task? Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).